# RESTful application using Spring boot to convert CSV to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, jackson

I am looking to build a Restful application using Spring Boot to convert CSV items to JSON objects and I want to understand the best approach to do it.

If CSV or CSV items can be passed through getMapping() method and then converted to JSON.

Comment: I am looking for a step by step guide, if possible?

Comment: Is there any size limit for the csv what could be the maximum size ? These kind of file handling approach usually depends upon the file size.

Comment: @VivekSingh for starters 100 to 200 rows csv we can assume.

Comment: File size man,  i.e. approx (in kb mb)

Comment: consider 5mb approx. @VivekSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be using POST Mapping, GET Mapping is not considered a good approach. Also I am using **jackson library** to read csv file and conversion as it make lot of things easier. Hope this generic code will help.

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/api/file-upload")
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadSingleFile (@RequestParam("csvFile") MultipartFile csvFile) {
  try{        
    serviceClass.convertCsvToJson(csvFile);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("File uploaded");
  }catch(Exception e){
     return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("File upload failed");
  }         
}
```

**Service class method**

```
public void convertCsvToJson(MultipartFile csvFile){
CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
try {
        List<Map<?, ?>> list;
        try (MappingIterator<Map<?, ?>> mappingIterator = csvMapper.reader()
                .forType(Map.class)
                .with(csvSchema)
                .readValues(csvFile)) {
            list = mappingIterator.readAll();
        }

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // You can also map csv content to you own pojo
        String jsonPretty = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(list);
                
        // Do something with json string        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of uploading csv file can take csv items via request body?

Comment: Yes! why not you just need to pass @RequestBody String csvString inside controller